# How to run fetch() in a loop?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I am new to nodejs and promise based request. I want to fetch the data from a remote server in a loop, and then create a JSON object from all fetched data.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const users = [];

const ids = await fetch('https://remote-server.com/ids.json');
console.log(ids);
// [1,2,3]

ids.forEach(id => {
    var user = await fetch(`https://remote-server.com/user/${id}.json`);
    users.push(user);
});

console.log(users);
```

expected output

```
    [
        {
            name: 'user 1',
            city: 'abc'
        },
        {
            name: 'user 2',
            city: 'pqr'
        },
        {
            name: 'user 3',
            city: 'xyz'
        }
    ]
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Console log will always return empty. Let me fiddle a promise function for you, let me warn you though. You can run into very long waiting times doing that.

Comment: So. do you want the requests to be launched in parallel or one-by-one?

Answer (score 10):

So to launch in parallel:

```
const ids = await fetch('https://remote-server.com/ids.json');
const userPromises = ids.map(id => fetch(`https://remote-server.com/user/${id}.json`));
const users = await Promise.all(userPromises);
```

to launch in sequence:

```
const users = [];
const ids = await fetch('https://remote-server.com/ids.json');
for(const id of ids){
    const user = await fetch(`https://remote-server.com/user/${id}.json`);
    users.push(user);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You forgot to add `async` in the `forEach`:

```
ids.forEach(async (id) => { // your promise is in another function now, so you must specify async to use await
    var user = await fetch(`https://remote-server.com/user/${id}.json`);
    users.push(user);
});
```

Comment: Beware. `Array.forEach` is not promise-aware, so this represents a "parallel" launching of all requests at once in "fire-and-forget" mode (bad for error-trapping) with no guarantee that the order of the `users` array will retain the same order as the `ids` array.